# WPF Image 'highlight' with DropShadowEffect can't bind color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, effects

I have created a UserControl called **ImageButton**, and I am using a DropShadowEffect on MouseOver to show the button as 'active'. However, I cannot seem to bind the Color property of my DropShadowEffect. Could anyone suggest why this doesn't work?

**XAML**;

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ActiveEffectTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:ImageButton}">
    <Image Name="image" Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}">
        <Image.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect 
                Color="{Binding HighlightColour}"
                BlurRadius="20" 
                ShadowDepth="0"
                Opacity="1" 
                Direction="0"/>
        </Image.Effect>
    </Image>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Code behind;

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightColourProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightColour", typeof(Color), typeof(ImageButton));

    public Color HighlightColour
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(HighlightColourProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HighlightColourProperty, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I solved this problem by putting the following into my binding;

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Controls:ImageButton}}
```

Answer (score 0):

That binding is relative to the `DataContext`, it should probably just be a `TemplateBinding` as well.

Comment: Tried that also, and no luck, I just get a default 'gray' colour in the effect.

Comment: @RJLohan: Do you set the colour anywhere? Are there binding errors in the output window of Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, just after creating the object, either in XAML or code - both give me the default gray.

Comment: Erm... somehow I have gotten this to work. I'm not even sure what I changed (I had given up and was working on other aspects of this control...), but when verifying prior to my last comment, it seems to work... :-|

Comment: OK, I found what the solution was; I added this line to my control's public default constructor;

     DataContext = this;

Comment: @RJLohan: That is **not** a good idea. (It prevents DataContext inheritance, so only do that if you are sure you will not ever need an inherited DataContext inside the control).

Comment: Yes, I've just learned from that mistake, as I am using that control inside a DataGrid, so I lost my DataContext. ;-) I fixed the problem with; RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Controls:ImageButton}} inside the Binding instead - that seems to have resolved both issues.

Comment: @RJLohan: The thing is that that relative source binding is exactly what the `TemplateBinding` should do.