# DropShadow Color DataBInding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a problem with a databinding. I have a class with properties to customize a style written with wpf. All properties works fine, except for the drop shadow color property from ContentPresenter. that is the only property that didn't work. I've tried a lot of things but no case. The property is called FontShadow ( type Color )

class code:

```
public class ButtonStyle
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Fill { get; set; }
    public String FontColor { get; set; }
    public Color FontShadow { get; set; }
    public String Image { get; set; }
    public int ImageWith { get; set; }
    public int ImageHeight { get; set; }
    public int FontSize { get; set; }
    public String FontName { get; set; }
    public Boolean Bold { get; set; }
    public String HAligment { get; set; }
    public String ButtonStyleName { get; set; }
}
```

the xaml code:

```
<Style x:Key="CommonActionButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        .....
                        <ContentPresenter DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}" x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Grid.RowSpan="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <ContentPresenter.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="2" Color="{Binding FontShadow, FallbackValue=Black}"/>
                            </ContentPresenter.Effect>
                            <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        .....
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

one a create a button i assign the style and the de data context (instance of ButtonStyle). Every property except FontShadow works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [WPF Image 'highlight' with DropShadowEffect can't bind color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198676/wpf-image-highlight-with-dropshadoweffect-cant-bind-color)

You should set the DataContext for this kind of databinding.